# How to fill color over other color on imageview area in android?

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, paint

**I have one imageview and i set image for filling the different colors. But when i fill color then other color is not fill on same area on imageview which previous color is filled. I use color pallet button for getting different color for fill on imageview. Below is my code.**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch (v.getId()){
        case  R.id.btn_color_one: {
            // do something for button 1 click
            initializeMP();
            playsound.start();

            paint.setColor(DARK_PINK);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));
//          path = new Path();
            break;

            }
        case  R.id.btn_color_two: {
            // do something for button 1 click

            initializeMP();
            playsound.start();


            paint.setColor(LIGHT_YELLOW);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(30);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
//          paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));
            break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting lots of r&d i got my answer:

```
private final Paint  mPaintSrcIn   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    private final Paint  mPaintDstIn   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    private final Paint  mPaintColor   = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final Paint  mPaintEraser  = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Canvas mLayerCanvas = new Canvas();

    private Bitmap mInnerShape;
    private Bitmap mOuterShape;
    private Bitmap mLayerBitmap;

    private ArrayList<DrawOp> mDrawOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();
    private DrawOp mCurrentOp = new DrawOp();

    private ArrayList<DrawOp> mUndoneOps = new ArrayList<DrawOp>();


    public DrawingView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mPaintSrcIn.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        mPaintDstIn.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        mPaintColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintColor.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaintColor.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mPaintEraser.set(mPaintColor);
        mPaintEraser.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mPaintEraser.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density * 4, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
    }

    public void setShape(int inner, int outer)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
        setShape(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), inner, options),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), outer, options));
    }

    public void setShape(int[] inner, int[] outer){
        for(int i=0;i<inner.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<outer.length;j++){
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;
                setShape(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), inner[i], options),
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), outer[j], options));
            }
        }

    }

    public void setShape(Bitmap inner, Bitmap outer)
    {
        mInnerShape = inner;
        mOuterShape = outer;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setDrawingColor(int color)
    {
        mCurrentOp.reset();
        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
        mCurrentOp.color = color;
    }

    public void setDrawingStroke(int stroke)
    {
        mCurrentOp.reset();
        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.PAINT;
        mCurrentOp.stroke = stroke;
    }

    public void enableEraser()
    {
        mCurrentOp.reset();
        mCurrentOp.type = DrawOp.Type.ERASE;
    }

    public void clearDrawing()
    {
        mDrawOps.clear();
        mUndoneOps.clear();
        mCurrentOp.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void undoOperation()
    {
        if(mDrawOps.size() > 0){
            DrawOp last = mDrawOps.remove(mDrawOps.size() - 1);
            mUndoneOps.add(last);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void redoOperation()
    {
        if(mUndoneOps.size() > 0){
            DrawOp redo = mUndoneOps.remove(mUndoneOps.size() - 1);
            mDrawOps.add(redo);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mLayerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mLayerCanvas.setBitmap(mLayerBitmap);

        if(mOuterShape != null){
            int dx = (w - mOuterShape.getWidth()) / 2;
            int dy = (h - mOuterShape.getHeight()) / 2;
            mMatrix.setTranslate(dx, dy);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(isInEditMode()){
            return;
        }

        // NOTE: Without extra bitmap or layer.. but HW Acceleration does not support setMaskFilter which means
        // eraser has strong edges whilst drawing.
        // @see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported 
        /*
        canvas.drawBitmap(mOuterShape, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.saveLayer(null, mPaint, Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mInnerShape, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.saveLayer(null, mPaintSrcIn, Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapDraw, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaintDraw);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.restore();
        */

        // Clear software canvas
        mLayerCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        // Draw picture from ops
        for(DrawOp op : mDrawOps){
            drawOp(mLayerCanvas, op);
        }
        drawOp(mLayerCanvas, mCurrentOp);

        // Mask the drawing to the inner surface area of the shape
        mLayerCanvas.drawBitmap(mInnerShape, mMatrix, mPaintDstIn);

        // Draw orignal shape to view
        canvas.drawBitmap(mOuterShape, mMatrix, null);

        // Draw masked image to view
        canvas.drawBitmap(mLayerBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private void drawOp(Canvas canvas, DrawOp op)
    {
        if(op.path.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        final Paint paint;
        if(op.type == DrawOp.Type.PAINT){
            paint = mPaintColor;
            paint.setColor(op.color);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
        }else{
            paint = mPaintEraser;
            paint.setStrokeWidth(op.stroke);
        }
        mLayerCanvas.drawPath(op.path, paint);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        final float x = event.getX();
        final float y = event.getY();

        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mUndoneOps.clear();
                mCurrentOp.path.moveTo(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                for(int i = 0; i < event.getHistorySize(); i++){
                    mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(event.getHistoricalX(i), event.getHistoricalY(i));
                }
                mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                mCurrentOp.path.lineTo(x, y);
                mDrawOps.add(new DrawOp(mCurrentOp));
                mCurrentOp.path.reset();
                break;
        }

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }


    }
```